# Invalid location of html tag <command> in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html

Given the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<menu id="html5menu" type="context" style="display:none" class="showcase">
  <command label="rotate" onclick="alert('rotate')"></command>
  <command label="resize" onclick="alert('resize')"></command>
  <menu label="share">
    <command label="twitter" onclick="alert('twitter')"></command>
    <hr>
    <command label="facebook" onclick="alert('facebook')"></command>
  </menu>
</menu>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a warning in Eclipse:

```
Invalid location of tag (command).
```

According to the examples I have found in the web the tag is being used correctly. Is this an Eclipse 'false' warning or am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.5.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201404011654